# Firebase Update query runs infinitely when I use variable

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I am using firebase and when I try to update values using some variable then it runs infinitely and if I used same code with static value then it works fine.

This is the function that I am using right now.

```
updatetotal(String value, String type, int update) async{

FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
int total, income, expense;
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users');

ref.orderByChild('username').equalTo(user.email).onValue.listen((event){
  DataSnapshot data = event.snapshot;
  var keys = data.value.keys;
  var todo = data.value;
  print(keys);
  print(value);
  print(type);
  for (var key in keys) {
    total = todo[key]['total'];
    income = todo[key]['income'];
    expense = todo[key]['expense'];
   if(type == 'Income'){
      total = total + int.parse(value);
      income = income + int.parse(value);
    }else{
      total = total - int.parse(value);
      expense = expense + int.parse(value);
    }
    ref.child(key).update({
      'total': total,//here if i user static value then it runs as expected
      'income': 60,
      'expense': 0
    });
  }
});

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using **onvalue** method because of that whenever value change it's call again and again. i change it to **once** and it's work fine.

i am keeping this question if anyone face same problem.